# Login error in python with smtplib library

Tags: python, email, security, authentication, passwords

I have a problem here, I input my email and password in this little program to send emails, they are correct (I double checked because that shows other error), but it shows me this error. Anyone knows the solution? TYIA

```
import smtplib

sender = 'myemail@gmail.com'
password = 'mypassword'

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login(sender, password)

receivers = ['email@gmail.com']

server.sendmail(sender, receivers, "message")
server.quit()
```

Error:

```
 File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    server.login(sender, password)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 623, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at\n5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor g25sm4834769vsq.21 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: Read the link from the error message!

Comment: Yup, as @KlausD. suggested, I read that link and it's talking about an app-specific password that's required. There is one other thing you could try, where you can turn off the [Less Secure Apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) setting for Gmail. This, however, makes your account vulnerable in a way, hence it's better if this account is not used for personal or business use.

Comment: @CavinDsouza that worked! haha, i did not understand the error message im sorry. How do i select your answer?

Comment: select your answer?? sorry, didn't get that...

Comment: I see green checkmarks in other questions?

Comment: Sorry im new here

Comment: Ohh, I see, you mean `upvote`, since mine was a comment and not an actual answer, you wouldn't be able to mark it as an 'accepted' answer.